# match string only if not match another string (similar to regex or ) regular expression?

Tags: regex

for example I have this text

```
 one
 two
```

I used a regular expression that contain `one|two`, that matched `one`.

However, if I use a regular expression that contains `on1222e|two` that matches `two`.

Comment: I'm really not sure what your actual question is, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: use a or but only if the first string not match

Comment: Cleaned up answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on1222e|two matches every text where on1222e or two exists.

ex) on1222e (o)  on1222ex (o)   on1222xe (x)  two (o)  twox (o) twxo (x)
     on1222eaaaatwo (o) on1222e|two (o)